# The Derivative of a Function of Two Variables wrt Both Variables

Tags: integration, derivatives

Let's consider the following function:

$f(x,y) = e^{5x} + e^{2x+3y}$.

How to calculate $\frac{d(f(x,y))}{dxdy}$?

I tried to calculate it as $\frac{d(e^{5x}+e^{2x+3y})}{dxdy}=\frac{d(e^{5x})}{dx} + \frac{d(e^{2x+3y})}{dxdy} = \frac{d(e^{5x})}{dx} + \frac{d(e^{2x})}{dx}\frac{d(e^{3y})}{dy}$. But I am sure it is not true.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: What you're writing doesn't make sense. Do you mean the *second* partial derivative $\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$?

Comment: Hallo no but I already got the answer from @Doug thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y))$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y))$  the order of differentiation does not matter.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y))\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}3e^{2x+3y}\\
6e^{2x+3y}$